# JQueryUI draggable object hidden behind droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've seen similar questions but I have tried all the answers people had accepted, and nothing is working. I am dynamically generating 3 divs, each with a ul that has draggable elements, and the ul themselves are droppable. However, unless I use helper with a clone, the dragged element disappears behind the other div/ul's that exist on the page. I do not want to drag a clone. I have tried using the stack option to no avail. I tried using the accept:draggable... no dice. It appears to be an issue with z-index. The hierarchy of the DOM for each of these 3 divs are:

```
<div><ul><li><a><h2>SomeContent</h2></a><li><ul><div>
```

and the below function makes the `<li>` draggable since what you click on is actually the `<a>`.

```
function moveme(hur){
    $hur = $(hur);
    $hur.parent().draggable({
        //helper: "clone",
        appendTo: "body",
        stack: "ul",
        cursor: "move"
    });

    $hur.parents('#stickyboard').children('.storediv').children('ul').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable"
    });

    $hur.parents('#stickyboard').children('.progressdiv').children('ul').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable"
    });

    $hur.parents('#stickyboard').children('.donediv').children('ul').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable"
        /*over: function(event,ui) {
            ui.draggable.css('z-index',100);
            ui.draggable.children('a').css('z-index',101);
        } */
    });
};
```

The issue is not what is being dragged, it is the fact that it disappears behind the other `<ul>`'s. Whatever you see commented out in the code are things I have tried with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you make some jsfiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88MYK/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you set `overflow:hidden` for the `.stickylist`. So it's the effect of hiding any overflow content, not caused by z-index. I understand that you may want to use `overflow:hidden` to prevent the item from being dragged out of the list towards the header. But it's of course not the way to go, because it causes a new problem that you asked. So to prevent the item from being dragged upwards out of the list, you can use the `containment` property which can accept an array of coordinates of the rectangle limiting the draggable region. The top left point should have the `y` to be the bottom of the header (it's not  necessarily exact) while the bottom right point should have the `y` and `x` as large as possible.

```
$('a').parent().draggable({
    //helper: "clone",
    appendTo: "body",
    stack: "ul",
    cursor: "move",
    /* add this */
    containment: [0,100,10000,10000]
});
```

### [Updated demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/88MYK/5/)

Here you can see [.draggable() containment option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment), it can receive an array.

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't even know about the containment property. Thanks so much!